# Create list of classes in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have class Ship:

```
class Ship {
    protected:
        int x, y;
        string type;
    public:
        Ship(string);
        void addCoordinates(int, int);
};
```

And in another class, `Side` I want to make list of Ships and add coordinates of all ships
in Side class i make a private variable:

```
Ship **list;
```

and in Constructor of Side class:

```
list = new Ship*[BufferSize];
```

Now, I'm getting file with ship type and coordinates:

```
A 3 2
B 4 5
C 7 3
```

and etc.

**In my loop, how I can create Ship object and add coordinate to this object?**

My variables for every loop:

```
string type = list[0]
int x = list[2]
int y = list [4]
```

Constructor of Ship object is getting ship type and assigning it to type variable, addCoordinates function takes 2 integers and assigns them to x and y.

Comment: Figure out how to make an object first. Then find out what a pointer is. Then figure out if you really want a dynamically allocated array of pointers. I suspect you would be fine with an `std::vector<Ship>`.

Comment: your syntax maxes no sense. How can you do `int x = list[2]` when `list` is type `Ship**`?

Comment: @RedAlert its getting list string from file. its just variables, type, x and y.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thats why I'm using BufferSize, and yes, In this program I need pointer :(

Comment: The first part doesn't make any sense. As for the second, if you really need a pointer you should probably explain why in the question.

Comment: like this I think: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3833510972f0258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If do not discuss the design of your approach the code could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

//...

std::string record;
size_t i = 0;

while ( i < BufferSize && std::getline( FileStream, record ) )
{
   if ( record.find_first_not_of( " \t" ) == std::string::npos ) continue;

   std::istringstream is( record );

   std::string type;

   is >> type;

   list[i] = new Ship( type );

   int x = 0, y = 0;

   is >> x >> y;

   list[i]->addCoordinates( x, y );

   ++i;
}
```

Without any doubts it would be much better if you would use `std::vector<Ship>` instead of your dynamically allocated array and dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: I think a for loop would read better here.

Comment: @Red Alert I agree that a for loop would look better.

Comment: @Red Alert I wrote the while loop because at first I thought about std::vector where variable i is not required because there would be used method push_back.:)

Comment: Thanks, I did something like that: `Ship *newShip;` creates variable in Ship type, `newShip = new Submarine(x, y, direction);` Assigns all needed values to Ship (Submarine is derived class) and then `this->list[counter++] = newShip;` adds newShip to list.